# how to get the integer column to integer list in informix

Tags: informix

To read an integer column into integer list

```
create function somedum()
returning int
define s LIST(INTEGER NOT NULL);
select id into s from informix.emptest;
end function

create table emptest(id int)

insert into emptest(id)values(7)
```

when I execute the above function

iam getting error as attached image

Comment: SQL Error :No cast from integer to set(integer not null)

Answer (score 0):

The Informix documentation on inserting elements into a `LIST` seems misleading to me, as my first impression of the example ( [Insert into a LIST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_477.htm) ) also led me to use the `SELECT INTO` syntax and get the same error:

```
-9634   No cast from integer to set(integer not null)
```

The `SELECT INTO` syntax can be used to copy/insert an entire `LIST`, not elements into the `LIST`.

To insert an element into the `LIST` ( or generally manipulate it's elements ) we need to use the Informix virtual table interface, in this case using the `TABLE` syntax to create a virtual table from the `LIST` which then can be used to do the usual insert/select/update/delete operations ( [Collection-Derived Table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1631.htm) ).

```
CREATE FUNCTION somedum()
RETURNING LIST( INTEGER NOT NULL ) AS alist;
DEFINE my_list LIST( INTEGER NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO TABLE( my_list ) SELECT id FROM emptest;

RETURN my_list;
END FUNCTION;
```

Executing the function we get:

```
EXECUTE FUNCTION somedum();

alist  LIST{7          }
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response and the above functionality worked like a charm

Comment: But, the thing is it is storing into the variable my_list.Iam unable to perform any operations on that variable
Please find the code

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLE( my_list1 ) select
((extend(current, year to second) + (dots.v_shift_coverage.pattern_end_time - datetime(00:00) hour to minute) - current)::interval minute(9) to minute)::char(10)::INTEGER from dots.v_shift_coverage where org_guid=orgid;
let sub=0;
let sub1=0;
let total=0;
for j = 0 to 4
  if (my_list(j) < my_list1(j))
  then
    if (my_list(j+1) > my_list1(j))
    then
      let sub=sub + my_list(j+1) - my_list1(j);
    end if;
  end if;
end for
if (my_list(0) > my_list1(4))
then
let sub1=my_list(0) - my_list1(4);
end if;
let total=sub+sub1;
return total;

Comment: Iam getting the below error.Please help

SQL Error[IX000]: Routine (my_list) can not be resolved

Comment: I have declared varibles before as well
DEFINE my_list LIST( INTEGER not null );
DEFINE my_list1 LIST( INTEGER not null );

Comment: the trace file gives me like this:
for loop variable j = 0
exception : looking for handler
SQL error = -674 ISAM error = 0  error string =  = "my_list"
exception : no appropriate handler

Comment: Informix Stored Procedure Language ( SPL)  does not support `LIST(index)` syntax to access individual elements. In fact, it does not seem to support indexed access to `LIST`or any `COLLECTION` . The only way I found on the documentation is using a `FOREACH` cursor, which is not appropriate for the logic you are trying to implement. One possibility is using temporary tables instead of `LIST` but it will make the procedure less performant. Another option is maybe implementing the function in `C`, as an Informix UDR.

Comment: Can you suggest how to use temporary tables for our logic

Comment: as I have stored the 2 result sets in two list varibles.Is it process those 2 lists with temp tables

Comment: It would really help us understand what is the desired output if you provided a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A simple example table with a few rows of data and the desired output when processing those rows, accompanied by an explanation of the logic that is to be applied. I could be that what you want can be done with just SQL statements.

Comment: Hi Luis,
The requirement for the question which is posted is satisfied. Thanks for the response.